# django NoReverseMatch Error when trying to link template to a view function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to add a delete object function to an app I'm building and when I try to link to it in my template, I get...

> NoReverseMatchError
> Reverse for 'delete_player' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['game/delete_player/(?P[0-9]+)$']

As far as I can tell, (I think) I'm using the correct format in my template. I'm thinking that there's an issue with the object's id not being passed correctly or just not passed at all. I've been looking around Stack overflow here and google to try and find a similar problem but I can't find anything that quite matches what I'm experiencing. Any advice is appreciated.

The models object in question that I'm trying to pass to the delete function is a choices field and looks like this.

```
class Player(models.Model):

    PLAYER_ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Quarterback'),
        (2, 'Runningback'),
        (4, 'Widereceiver'),
        (5, 'Tightend'),
        (6, 'Kicker'),
        
    )
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=PLAYER_ROLE_CHOICES)
```

The model uses a form in forms.py

```
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):

    quarterback_name = forms.CharField(label='Quarterback', max_length=100)
    runningback_name = forms.CharField(label='Runningback', max_length=100)
    widereceiver_name = forms.CharField(label='Widereceiver', max_length=100)
    tightend_name = forms.CharField(label='Tightend', max_length=100)
    kicker_name = forms.CharField(label='Kicker', max_length=100)
    
    def save(self):
        quarterback_name = self.cleaned_data.get('quarterback_name')
        Quarterback.objects.create(name=quarterback_name)
        runningback_name = self.cleaned_data.get('runningback_name')
        Runningback.objects.create(name=runningback_name)
        widereceiver_name = self.cleaned_data.get('widereceiver_name')
        Widereceiver.objects.create(name=widereceiver_name)
        tightend_name = self.cleaned_data.get('tightend_name')
        Tightend.objects.create(name=tightend_name)
        kicker_name = self.cleaned_data.get('kicker_name')
        Kicker.objects.create(name=kicker_name)
```

My delete object function in views.py looks like this

```
def delete_player(request, id):
    player = Player.objects.get(id=id)
    player.delete()
    
    return redirect('show')
```

The paths in urls.py are these...

```
path('delete_player/<int:id>', views.delete_player, name="delete_player")
path('show/<int:id>', views.show, name="show")
```

I'm using this in my html template.

```
<tr>  
     <td>{{ QB }}  
           <a href="{% url 'delete_player' player.id %}">Delete</a>  
        </td> 
        
    </tr>
```

The template that is being rendered is called "show.html" and is rendered by this function in views.py

```
def show(request, id): 
    
    player = Player.objects.get(id=id)

    user = request.user

    if user.is_authenticated: 

        try:
            QB = Quarterback.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            QB = 'empty'

        try:
            RB = Runningback.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            RB = 'empty'

        try:     
            WR = Widereceiver.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            WR = 'empty'

        try:
            TE = Tightend.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            TE = 'empty' 

        try:    
            K = Kicker.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            K = 'empty' 

        print(QB)


        context = {
            'QB': QB[0:],
            'RB': RB[0:],
            'WR': WR[0:],
            'TE': TE[0:],
            'K': K[0:],
            'player': player
        }


        return render(request,"game/show.html", context)
```

Comment: Can you share the view that renders the template? Likely you did not pass something like `player`.

Comment: Sure. Let me bring that up.

Comment: Your `context` does not contain a `player`... Exactly what would the value of `player.id` be then?

Comment: Ahh! That makes a lot of sense. Ok, I've added "id" as a parameter to my function in views.py, added an instance called "player" to def (delete_player), and changed the "show" url accordingly. I've edited my code in the original post here to show the changes. Now it's giving me a 404 error???

Answer (score 0):

The urlpattern is expecting an int:id but in the template you have no player in the context so player.id sends out an empty value causing the error.

After looking a little better I realized that you have one model "Player" with a CHOICES field, and yet in the form save() method you go and create all sorts of objects, when in fact those should all be Player objects with a choice field indicating their role.

For a moment i thought that each role had a one-to-one relationship with the Player model but from the way you create them they all seem to be standalone.

So, depending on what's your goal i think you have multiple options here:

1. Connect your player to each role with a one-to-one relationship, so
   that each player can cover more than one role at the same time, and
   once you delete the player his roles are also removed from the
   connected tables (on_delete=models.CASCADE)
2. Stick to one model only (Player) and just use the CHOICES field to differentiate among them. This is a better choice if different player types don't have any unique characteristics (sorry i don't know the first thing about American Football). If you go down this path then you can just use a class-based TemplateView and override the get_context_data method to pass to the template anything you want (the Player model in your case). Here's a quick example:

   class HomePageView(TemplateView):

   ```
   template_name = 'home.html'
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['locations'] = Location.objects.all()
       return context
   ```

I don't know your project but based on what i can gather i'd recommend you the second option. By adopting it you'd basically be able to navigate anywhere just using the player.id. Then creating a delete function would take you less than a minute.

I warmly recommend you to use exclusively class-based views as they are incredibly powerful and reusable. They have a bit of a learning curve but the benefits compound greatly over time.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed analysis and answer. I really don't know anything about class-based views. Would that example you showed go into views.py?

Comment: Yes it would go in views.py. You can find a great explanation of generic views here : https://dj4e.sites.uofmhosting.net/lessons/django_generic